# What does steel beams mean here?

Tags: meaning

From *Legend* by Marie Lu:

> It’s early evening, but it’s already pitch-black outside, and the JumboTrons’ reflections are visible in the street’s puddles. I sit on a crumbling window ledge three stories up, hidden from view behind rusted steel beams. This used to be an apartment complex, but it’s fallen into disrepair. Broken lanterns and glass shards litter the floor of this room, and paint is peeling from every wall. In one corner, an old portrait of the Elector Primo lies faceup on the ground. I wonder who used to live here—no one’s cracked enough to let their portrait of the Elector sit discarded on the floor like that.

What are the rusted steel beams here ? I can't imagine what the the author is saying here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The apartment complex is in disrepair

Something like this image

[image]

Comment: Ya but how come he is hidden from view if the steel beams are a part of  the room and he is sitting on the ledge.

Answer (score 1):

You might have further clues in the rest of the text regarding the location of the mentioned jumbotron, but I would imagine the jumbotron being constructed directly in front of the building's facade, so the steel beams making up most of it's under-structure would be in front of some of the windows.

[image: Jumbotron with visible steel beams underneath]

I can't give you any references, but I have a vague recollection of characters in multiple noir/cyberpunkesque movies lounging in similarly decrepit window openings, behind the trusses of jumbotrons.

May be a trope?